# Jetpack compose `navController.popBackStack()` is not working with arguments

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

lets say I have 3 screens named `A`,`B` and `C`.

I can navigate to `B` from `A` and navigate to `C` from `B`.

when I want to navigate to `B` from `A` I dont have any argument to pass to `B`.

but when I want to get back into `B` while I am in `C` I might pass an argument.

my problem is when im in `C` and I want to back to `B`,`navController.popBackStack` is not working.

here is my `NavHost`:

```
   val navigationController = rememberNavController()
   NavHost(
        navController = navigationController,
        startDestination = Screen.Intro.name
    ) {
        composable(
             route = "B?countryCode={countryCode}",
             arguments = listOf(navArgument("countryCode") {
                 nullable = true
                 type = NavType.StringType
                 defaultValue = null
             })
         ) { navBackStack ->
             val countryCode: String? = 
             navBackStack.arguments?.getString("countryCode")
             B(navigationController, countryCode)
         }
```

and here is `navigationController.popBackStack()` when I want to back to `B`while im in `C`:

```
val backStackRoute = if (chosenCountry == null) "B"
else "B?countryCode=${chosenCountry.code}"

navigationController.popBackStack(
    route = backStackRoute,
    inclusive = false
)
```

when I press the Button which is responsible for going back to `B` nothing happens and I get this log:
`I/NavController: Ignoring popBackStack to destination -1599746084 as it was not found on the current back stack`

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: @EunhaEonnie I remember I solved this, but sadly I do not have access to that source code any more!